# Should I accept an answer while still there are more errors and lead to new errors?

Tags: discussion

One of my questions was involving more than one error generally related with library problems. Here is a tricky situation. There was an answer that corrects one of my mistakes and after I added that library, nearly whole error log changed. There were still problems related with libraries.

This answer solved one of my problems but not all. If I accept this answer, users will see the question and will not understand what was the real problem because it was not the complete answer. If changed the log, the answer was going to be meaningless...

So, I accepted his answer and asked another question related with new log but still the question that I asked was not solved completely. What should I do to leave a question and an answer that will be an answer for the others? Should I edit my question and add a warning about it or should I not accept that as an answer?

Comment: Which question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738662/spring-datasource-emf-jdbc-driver-class-loading-error This one?

Comment: Yeap, after that I added nearly 3-4 more jars to my library, but mysql library one of them...

Comment: The fact that you constantly think that you need to ask a new question immediately upon encountering every new error suggests that **you need to improve your debugging skills** before you keep asking new questions on [main]. You have a chameleon question problem. Or something like that. I'm sure gnat or someone will post a link to it...

Comment: @Cupcake I did not asked new question for every problem I encountered, ok there were problems about me seeing that problem for this question, after that there were 2-3 library added by me before asking one final question. But, thank you for your answer, I will try harder to ask specific questions after trying harder to solver it.

Comment: @SerhatC wow, did I [type that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265794/should-i-accept-an-answer-while-still-there-are-more-errors-and-lead-to-new-erro#comment62185_265794)? I don't know what I was thinking! I didn't actually take a close look at your question. I was just speculating. Don't take my word as the definitive truth, it's just a flimsy opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The green tick mark is entirely your choice, use it for the answer that helped you **personally**.

There is also the possibility that you may get better answers in future, in that case, choose the answer that helped you the most in solving your issue.

Also, if you solve the issue, it is advisable to compose a good detailed answer and post it. That helps future users.

**Related post:**
[After answering questions and also being accepted require to help if questioner gets in some other problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167804/245167)
[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/245167)

**Potential Side Effect**
Thanks to Cupcake for [highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265794/should-i-accept-an-answer-while-still-there-are-more-errors-and-lead-to-new-erro#comment62186_265797)
 the potential side effect:

> This kind of behavior could lead to the problem where the original problem is solved, but the OP immediately encounters an entirely new problem, and so continuously modifies the original question by adding an entirely new question. That is a waste of time for the original answerer, and any future readers arriving at a question and expecting answers that correspond to it.

It is called "Chameleon behaviour". We should take care to avoid this behaviour, as it is generally frowned upon.

**Related post:**
[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/163250)
[Guidance To Avoid Chameleon Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169052/245167)

Comment: Be careful, according to the OP's description, this kind of behavior could lead to the problem where the original problem is solved, but the OP immediately encounters an entirely new problem, and so continuously modifies the original question by adding an entirely new question. That is a waste of time for the original answerer, and any future readers arriving at a question and expecting answers that correspond to it. I think people around here call it the "chameleon question" problem...or something like that.

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks, am looking at the posts related to chameleon questions now...didn't know about this..

Comment: Ok, I understood what a chameleon question is. I'll try to improve my skills to ask better questions and accept answers that solve my questions completely.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion here's one: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/163250).

Answer (score 0):

(It's always up to you to choose to accept an answer or not.)

If an answer is at least a partial answer that has helped you overcome part of your problem, it's often worth upvoting it. If you need a little bit more help, write a comment. It is quite frequent for a couple of types of errors to be closely related, so asking whether the second error might be a side effect or closely related to the first fix is appropriate.

However, there's a point where the answerer might just say that it's a completely different problem. Often, with a little more investigation, you may find subsequent errors might come from a completely different problem.

Let's just say that your initial error is "*Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]*", and you get an answer telling you to add that driver to the classpath.

You could quite easily have a second error immediately after fixing this that says something along the lines of "*no such database*", "*no such table*", "*invalid syntax in SQL query*".

After a quick comment, the answer could just say something like "check your connection parameters, just in case", but expecting the answerer to know what your table structure or which SQL queries you're making would be quite unreasonable within the context of the initial question.

Breaking your problem into sub-problems (and realising when they are sub-problems) is not just good for asking question on Stack Overflow, it's also a good approach to problem solving in general.

If you're [developing an application using tools like Spring and related frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24738662/372643), you're likely to encounter a number of problems that may or may not be directly related. It's not a criticism of Spring, but the fact is that you're visibly trying to make multiple things to work together. Stack Overflow is generally not the right place to ask about the behaviour of a large piece of code without trying to isolate the problem.

What *not* to do is to unaccept and re-accept the answer multiple times, asking for new little comments every time. This will indeed catch the attention of the answerer, but not in a good way.