# Is it appropriate to ask more questions in the comments section of the answer

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to ask more questions in the comments section of an answer? Or is it better to create a new question?

Comment: You can ask clarifying questions if you feel they are necessary to understand the answer. If you have a totally separate issue that arises after applying the answer you've been given to the previous question, you should post a new question.

Comment: What kinds of questions would you like to ask?

Comment: Why are you asking this? What does the [help centers's page on comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) tell you about this situation?

Comment: @CodyGray I see what you did there.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265794 Also see:[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/163250)

Comment: @Josh Caswell, Thanks! I think "Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;" in your link answered my question.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions